# Angular-cli installation issue on windows 8.1

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm not finding any work around for the following ,

> Failed to install @angular/cli using npm

Error:

> > > npm install -g -f @angular/cli
> > >        npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
> > >        [ ...............] \ fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule chokidar@1.7.0 checking installable status

even I tried without -f still getting issue. As per the forum suggestion , tried

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean  
npm cache verify  
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Even I try to install externally chokidar package , even it is not resolved .

My current

```
 Node : 8.6.0
 npm : 5.3.0
```

Even I tried with latest node version also, issue not resolved

Comment: I see a warning there, where is the error? Are you running this as administrator?

Comment: I'm in  admin  mode ,  its struck ": sill resolveWithNewModule chokidar@1.7.0 checking installable status",  I left for more than hours but its  no progress after that .

Comment: Did you try this more than once? If so, do you get the same behavior each time?

Comment: Yes , I tried  multiple times  with different suitable version ,  still same  result

Answer (score 0):

try to install the angular/cli using git command line on windows or run the command in the administrator mode and wait till the process finishes and see the results and I think this will help you .

Comment: Yes , I tried installing using git bash shell also , but  I didn't find any  progress,   its struck ": sill resolveWithNewModule chokidar@1.7.0 checking installable status", I left for more than hours but its no progress after that